# How to communicate from client child to parent server component in nextjs 13 beta

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Obviously I'm lacking understanding of basic principles here.

I'm doing something like this in my *parentServerComponent*:

```
parentServerComponent.js: 

// some logic and data fetching happening here

return (
  <childClientComponent1 />
  <childClientComponent2 />
)
```

The idea is:

1. In *childClientComponent1*, the user selects an Id that I want to emit to the parent.
2. In *parentServerComponent*, I want to fetch an object for the given Id
3. In *parentServerComponent*, I want to pass the fetched object as property to *childClientComponent2*

Coming from VueJS, I was first thinking about emitting an event with the selected Id from child to parent but this pattern does not seem to exist in React. I tried passing a callback function from *parentServerComponent* to *childClientComponent1* which is not allowed: "Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components because they're not serializable"

The nextjs 13 beta documentation is reading that server components should be used as far as possible and that data fetching should be done in server components.

But how can I achieve that?

Comment: do you have error.jsx

Comment: Yes, why does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did wrong: I was thinking in Single Page Application instead of actually navigating between pages using `<Link>` and React Router.

Instead of passing the selected ID back from *childClientComponent1* to *parentServerComponent* solely on the client, I need to navigate to the target URL route (/object/[id]) which triggers a new request to the server page.tsx component on the server where I can fetch the object for [id] and pass it to the *childClientComponent2*.